# Azure App Services - MVC5 WebApp missing css files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I was planning to migrate to Azure Web Services for hosting my MVC5 web app.
I successfully added continious integration with my git repo which sits on AzureDevOps (formerly known as VSTS). Azure has pulled my repo and I can see my website on .azurewebsites.net but without my css files?
When I view sourceCode I can see different build output as I can see in my localhost (MS Build and deploy regulary everything works fine).
Apparently, Azure all my css files added to one line:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=dO_Yd8KQtA539X-oIYSdv6BQQYt4J4R-RXerlkp23281" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

in my localhost in my head section of the Layout.cshtml is:

```
    <link href="/Content/css/google-font.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/font-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="/Content/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Why Azure do this? I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1, while I saw on Azure WebServices when I create newly one it is 4.7. However, it isn't a source of this problem, right?
Because I have a free trial, I can't contact the Azure Help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured bundling and minification?

It is off by default in debug mode.
you can turn it on by setting compilation debug="false"

When you deploy to Azure it deploys in release mode which turns on bundling. 
you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification)

Comment: I'd check into this, because this seems like the solution. It has nothing to do with Azure, as far as I know.